# Recuperar información del fetch en una variable externa

Tags: javascript, promesas, ecmascript-6

Estoy intentando gestionar las promesas para poder utilizar el resultado en una variable donde genero un código HTML, pero no lo consigo.

¿Alguien me echa una mano?

Dejo el código:

```
const entries = [1,2,3,4]

var result = getData(entries)

function getData(entries) {
  var topicsHTML = ''
  for (const entry of entries) {
    return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${entry}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => topicsHTML += `<p >${data.title}</p>`)
      .catch(console.error)
  };
  return topicsHTML;
};

console.log(result); // Promise {<pending>}
console.log(result.then(res => res)); // Promise {<pending>}

// Código esperado : <p>Title 1</p><p>Title 2</p>....
```

Comment: Hola, usar `async/await` es una posibilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `async/await` como te comenté.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea obtener una serie de datos al consumir una API, usando una serie de llamadas a la misma usando diferentes parámetros que se almacenan en una lista.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para lograr lo que te propones podrías usar una función `async`. Debes verificar la [compatibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Browser_compatibility) del navegador si deseas implementar esta funcionalidad en tu página.

Una forma en la que podrías lograrlo es la siguiente:

```js
const entries = [1,2,3,4];
const btn = document.getElementById('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = await getData(entries);
});

async function getData(entries) {
  let topicsHTML = ''
  for (const entry of entries) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${entry}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    topicsHTML += `<p >${data.title}</p>`;
   }
   return topicsHTML;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button">Ejecutar</button><br><br>
<label for="resultado">Resultado:</label><br><hr>
<div id="resultado" name="resultado"></div><br>
```

Como puedes ver en el código, usamos la función `async` para poder realizar la tarea de forma secuencial (sincrónica) y de esta forma podemos devolver la `Promise` resuelta y no en estado `pending`.

**¿Cómo funciona?**

Cuando realizamos una declaración de función tipo `async`, estamos diciendo que la misma realizará una tarea asíncrona o con llamadas a funciones que devuelven una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise). En este caso `fetch` es una función que devuelve una promesa. Por lo tanto, debemos esperar que dicha promesa sea resuelta (o rechazada). Esto lo hacemos usando el operador [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await).

Una vez que obtenemos la respuesta con `fetch`, usamos el método [json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Body/json) del objeto [`reponse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Response) recibido, y dado que dicho método también devuelve una Promesa, debemos usar nuevamente el operador `await`.

Ahora, podrás notar que la función [`callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) que he pasado al evento del botón también es una función `async`, esto debe ser así ya que dentro de dicha función hago una llamada a una función `async` (getData()), por lo tanto debo esperar que dicha función realice su tarea antes de asignar el resultado a la variable, que en este caso es el `innerHTML` del elemento `div` creado para este ejemplo.

Puedes leer un poco más sobre [funciones `async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) en MDN.

También puedes leer más sobre la [API Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) en MDN

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas.